# Squeryl and scala : fetch by multiple values using the in clause

Tags: playframework, squeryl

I'm using scala to get my values from the following url : **?booksId=1,4,6&autorId=2**

To retrieve the booksid values i did this :  **params.get("booksId")** and the output of this is : **Some(1, 4, 6)**. Some is the function added by Scala !! So what i want is to select all the booksId in my DB

```
(l.authorId like params.get("authorId").?) and
(l.booksId in params.get("booksId").?)
```

I converted the string to a list and i get the output : **List((1,4,6))** but still didn't work, but i put the list directly **List((1,4,6))** it works:  Do you know why ? thanks

Comment: `Some` is an `Option` type and basic Scala construct, [this guide](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html) can help you understand more

Comment: Still it didn't answer my question though ! but thanks for the guide